# Ошибка в ProGuard

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-play, proguard

Ошибка во время компиляции проекта android, а так же во время создания apk файла с применением ProGuard

Установил в приложение Google play services lib. Все запускалось и отображалось, но после попутки создания apk для публикации в Intellij IDEA, я получил ошибку, что файл не оптимизирован. Погуглил, нашел, что нужно ProGuard использовать. Поставил галку во время создания файла, и посыпались ошибки.

Ниже копи-паст из лога.

```
Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced method 'void setShowsDialog(boolean)' in class com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.google.android.gms.common.api.d

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Fragment getParentFragment()' in class android.app.Fragment

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b: can't find referenced method 'boolean getUserVisibleHint()' in class android.app.Fragment

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b: can't find referenced method 'void setUserVisibleHint(boolean)' in class android.app.Fragment

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in class android.view.ViewTreeObserver

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.ed: can't find referenced method 'boolean isActiveNetworkMetered()' in class android.net.ConnectivityManager

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.es: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.es: can't find referenced method 'void setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] Warning: there were 10 unresolved references to program class members.

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]          You may need to recompile them and try again.

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)

Error:ProGuard: [MyApplication]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ненужно использовать ProGuard  
мои телепатические способности подсказывают, что у вас АПК не сжимался zip-ом.  
У меня была такая проблема, IDEA по этому поводу показывала ворнинг. У вас не показывает?  
zipalign.exe должен находиться по пути <путь_к_андроид_сдк>\tools\zipalign.exe

Comment: Показывал предупреждение. да, речь шла о zipalign. 
metalurgys, Вы можете мне рассказать в подробностях о процессе добавления ключа, сжатия и выравнивании proguard'ом ?

выровнять нужно для альфа-тестирования. Google Play не принимает без него.

ЗЫ: Благодарю за предыдущий Ваш ответ. Палец вверх пока не могу поставить, т.к. очков у меня недостаточно. Но наградить вроде получилось.

Comment: zipalign.exe нашел в папке 
<Android>\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0
скопировал его в 
\sdk\tools\ завтра буду пробовать запустить выравнивание арк файла.
С этим разобрался, а вот с описанием proguard нет.

Comment: зачем вам ProGuard? это не необходимая штука! Если вы не знаете, как им пользоваться, то он вам 99% не нужен!

Comment: Угу, да проблема в zipalign, который в новых релизах SDK "сел" в каталог `SDK/build-tools`, а IDEA ожидает его в `SDK/tools` - перенесите и все заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала следует сказать, что IntelliJIDEA является, фактически, устаревшей средой для разработки под Android.
Хотя бы потому, что в Google разработали собственную IDE на ее основе - Android Studio.
По умолчанию IDE от Google использует сборщик проектов Gradle, с которым довольно неплохо интегрирован ProGuard, чего нельзя сказать о более раннем сборщике ANT.

Для того, чтобы собрать проект и применить к нему ProGuard, как уже выше было сказано, действительно будет необходимо собрать, подписать( с помощью JarSigner ), оптимизировать( используя ZipAlign ) и только затем применять ProGuard. Разумеется, все это делается в автоматическом режиме. Если с первыми двумя операциями проблем нет( на выходе получается пригодный для маркета APK ), то с ProGuard`ом действительно могут быть проблемы.

Для его использования необходим файл **proguard-android.txt**, наполненный дефолтными конфигурациями и располагающийся в директории `<Android SDK>/tools/proguard`.
Его содержимое можно найти, например, **[здесь](http://pastebin.com/7rNJkns0)**.
Без него ProGuard просто не сработает. В случае с Gradle( а это лучший случай ), появляется также возможность добавить дополнительные настройки, разместив их в файле **proguard-rules.pro** с проектом. Обычно туда добавляются настройки, указывающие какие конкретно классы/методы оставлять без изменения.

Далее необходимо будет добавить конфигурации, касающиеся ProGuard`а в файл конфига сборки Gradle:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: все понятно. спасибо. Я решил выключить proGuard.